# cron couldn't run Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, cron

The code in crontab `0 * * * * cd /home/scrapy/foo/ && scrapy crawl foo >> /var/log/foo.log`

It failed to run the crawl, as there was no log in my log file.
I tested using `0 * * * * cd /home/scrapy/foo/ && pwd >> /var/log/foo.log`, it echoed '/home/scrapy/foo' in log.

I also tried `PATH=/usr/local/bin` and `PATH=/usr/bin`, but no success.

I'm able to run it manually by typing `cd /home/scrapy/foo/ && scrapy crawl foo` in command line.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Rather than running the crawl as `root`, use `crontab -u user -e` to create a crontab for `user`, and run as `user`.